# how to handle require/DI in Laravel package angularjs?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel

I would like to incorporate an angularjs app in a package for laravel. I'm still getting my brain wrapped around loading assets in a regular blade template when they are in the package's vendor directory so I'm not sure how you set up the javascript dependency injection for an angular app.

On standalone apps, I've used addons such as angular-autoload.js or require.js and I see examples for using webpack or mix in a laravel website, but they don't provide details on how to do it in a package dependency, especially as relates to asset paths.

I prefer to have my angularjs packages handle their own autoloading/dependency-injection as opposed to having to pre-load everything in  tags.  But I'm not sure how (in angularjs or requirejs) to tell it where to get files in a package's vendor/packagename/assets/js or css directory.  Is this even possible?

Short of building the app in one huge file that includes everything (which I prefer not to do as I like the modularity of separating directives and controllers into their own .js files) I'm not sure how to do that in a laravel 'package'.

So as a for-example - I have a test angular I set up to test autoloading.  The main.js looks like:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "app",
    paths: {
        'jquery'        : "//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0",
        'angular'       : '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular',
        'angular-route' : '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular-route',
        'angularAMD'    : '//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/marcoslin/angularAMD@0.2.1/dist/angularAMD',
        'ngload'        : '//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/marcoslin/angularAMD@0.2.1/dist/ngload',

        'MyService' : "services/MyService",
        'MyController' : "controllers/MyController"
    },
    shim: {
        'jquery' : {
            'exports' : "$"
        },
        'angularAMD': {
            'deps' : ['angular']
        },
        'ngload': {
            'deps' : [ 'angularAMD' ]
        },
        'angular-route' : {
            'deps' : ['angular'],
        }
    },
    deps: [
        'jqueryLoader',
        'services',
        'controllers',
        'app'
    ]
});
```

which I load with require.js in my index file with:

```
<script data-main="app/main.js"
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.6/require.js"> 
</script>
```

What I'm unclear on is how, in the main.js I specify the locations of the services and controller paths and how in the src tag I specify the location of the main.js to start the whole thing rolling (when it's in a 'package' required using composer inside of a laravel instance)

Comment: I can get it to work if I 'publish' the assets and then include the 'vendor/myname/packagename/js/app' prefix in front of each file. I'm wondering if there's something to generate that path as needed? Such as somehow tying it in with mix/webpack which I know very little about how to use - no less use in a package.